# Kotlin code to openapi call not working beyond building jsonObjectRequest

Tags: kotlin, openai-api, gpt-3, chatgpt-api

I am making a call from Kotlin code to openai api (gpt-3.5-turbo). I am using a valid my_token for auth. My code is as below -

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_generate)

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

        val outputText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.present_final)

        val prompt = "say hi"
        val requestBody = JSONObject()
        requestBody.put("model", "gpt-3.5-turbo")
        requestBody.put("messages", JSONArray()
            .put(JSONObject().put("role", "system").put("content", "You are a helpful assistant."))
            .put(JSONObject().put("role", "user").put("content", prompt))
        )


        val jsonObjectRequest = object: JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions",
            requestBody,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                try {
                    val generatedResponse = parseGeneratedResponse(response.toString())
                    runOnUiThread {
                        outputText.text = generatedResponse
                    }
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    Log.e("GenerateActivity", "JSONException while parsing response: ${e.message}")
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("GenerateActivity", "Exception: ${e.message}")
                }
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Log.e("GenerateActivity", "API request failed: ${error.message}")
            }
        ) {
            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                return mutableMapOf(
                    "Content-Type" to "application/json",
                    "Authorization" to "Bearer <my_token>"
                )
            }
        }

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }
```

when I debug, the code flow is not getting inside the line **val jsonObjectRequest = object: JsonObjectRequest(**.

I trid using the same my_token and same prompt through a simple python script using request lib and it is working fine. Please help with the kotlin code. Thanks!